# Google maps api v2 polylines android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline

I need to draw the polylines on the google map from a `ArrayList` each time a new `LatLng` is found whose color is according to percentage of the current speed to that of max speed of the vehicle.

I am using the following code for that:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Route.speeds.size(); i++)
        {
            colorOfGraph = graphColor(Route.speeds.get(i), maxSpeed);
            polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().addAll(Route.points).width(5).color(colorOfGraph);
            Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
            Route.paths.add(polyline);
        }
```

where `Route.speeds` is an `ArrayList` having all the speeds maintained in it, `maxspeed` is the max speed of the vehicle which changes when `maxspeed` of the vehicle changes and color of polyline is according to %age of max speed, as the max speed increases, the color of the previous polylines should also change, so I need to draw it again. So my qs here is how to redraw the polylines  each time i get a new latlng.

SO please anyone help me with this problem.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: what's exactly your question? sorry, but right now it sounds like you want someone else to code it for you...

Comment: i dont want that actually i am  just asking for help to resolve my issue i have already written the code

Comment: but you haven't said what is your issue! there is no problem description in your post. there is no question!

Comment: i edited my question.Can u please check now.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, in order to "redraw" the `Polyline` you have two options:

1. Simulate it by removing it using `Polyline.remove()`. Then build it again using `PolylineOptions` and add with `GoogleMap.addPolyline()`.
2. Change the attributes of the polyline. You can set it's color using `setColor(int)` and set points using `setPoints(List<LatLng>)`. The polyline should automatically redraw itself on the map after you call any of these methods.

In both cases you have to keep references to the created polylines, but you already do it in the line:

```
Route.paths.add(polyline);
```

If I were you I would go with the second option since you won't have to recreate the whole `Route.paths` collection. Instead, you would have to add just one polyline - the one that goes from the previously-last `LatLng` to the last `LatLng` recorded.

Comment: No, actually i want to redraw it again with different color, not append it in the previous latlng recorded. So i would have to remove the polyline using Polyline.remove() right?

Comment: both these options are equivalent if you only change points and color - just pick one that suits you best.